# Error while debuying umbraco

Tags: .net, umbraco

Server Error in '/' Application.

CS0012: The type 'umbraco.interfaces.IApplicationStartupHandler' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'interfaces, Version=1.0.4643.18922, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

[image: Error Message]

Doesn't understand why this error is occurred , the project runs good for some time then this error occurs and then I have to work on the back up version of this project. Because me unable to solve this error and the worst part is I have to start applying the code again.

Does anyone have solution

Comment: Do all the Umbraco .dll's exist in your \bin folder ? Looks like you are missing some of them or missing some references in your project.

Comment: martijn van der put , yup I have all the Umbraco .dll's in my \bin folder

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have a reference to the 'interfaces.dll' file, and make sure it is available in the /bin folder of your installation of Umbraco.

Check your references in Visual Studio; maybe you are referencing the wrong file or wrong version of the file 'interfaces.dll'.